# How to change html text at specific times with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to change html text at specific times with javascript
for example

```
<p class="timer">00:00</p>
```

Comment: See the docs of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to precise the time and [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to change the text!

Comment: Have you even tried once to search for it?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has the functions `setInterval` and `setTimeout` to time things. `setInterval` takes its first argument as a function, and its second as the interval at which to run it (in miliseconds).

First, you will want to work out how long until the next minute, which can be achieved by doing

`60 - (new Date().getSeconds())`

After this time, you want the code to repeat once every minute (once every 60000 milliseconds).

So, let's write the function that replaces the contents of the element with the current time first

```
function replaceContentsOfElement(){
    document.querySelector(".timer").innerHTML = new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes()
}
```

The next step is to combine `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, and our function to produce the result. After that function definition, you can write

```
setTimeout(function(){
    replaceContentsOfElement(),
    setInterval(replaceContentsOfElement, 60000)
}, 60 - (new Date().getSeconds()))
```

Alternatively, you could just check every second and update the time, but that would not be as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will change the text after 1 second. Just so you can see how it works.

```
// HTML
<p id="myId" class="timer">00:00</p>
<p id="myId2" class="timer">00:00</p>

// JS
var text = document.getElementById("myId");
var text2 = document.getElementById("myId2");

var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 1000);

function myCallback() {
  text.textContent = "Changed after 1 second";
}

var timer = setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime(){
  text2.textContent = new Date().getHours() + ':' + new Date().getMinutes() + ':' + new Date().getSeconds();
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/Sacki2013/pen/QdXEzV)

Notice when the page load it shows '00:00', after one second it is updated.

EDIT - The pen now displays the time and will update every second, forever.